# MySQL failing to ALTER TABLE which is being actively written to

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, innodb

In one of the use cases of my application, I have two concurrent *MySQL* connections:

- one actively writing to a table named `T` (actually, continuously updating a single row in this table), and
- another one executing a DDL against the very same table (`ALTER TABLE`, adding 8 new columns and extending one column from `varchar(80)` to `varchar(2000)`). The DDL is expected to eventually complete.

The columns in the `UPDATE` DML are **not** affected by the DDL.

The table contains only a single row (the one being `UPDATE`'d).

**Analysis**

What I observe when an integration test covering this use case is run is a test time out (the table is being so actively written to, so that the DDL never completes), but only for *MySQL* 5.7. Normally, the test is expected to complete in under 30 seconds on our hardware (which indeed happens for *MySQL* 5.6 and 8.0), but for *MySQL* 5.7 even 200 seconds is not sufficient. I have experimented with different `ALGORITHM` and `LOCK` values (see [13.1.8 ALTER TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)), with no luck.

When I profile my application (*MySQL* 5.7 case), I observe that 99% of CPU time is spent reading from a socket (i. e. waiting for *MySQL* to respond that the table has been altered), but the database instance is a sort of a black box to me -- of course I have `performance_schema` enabled and can run queries against it, but I have no idea which exact information I am looking for.

**Synthesis**

At the same time, I failed to reduce the problem to a minimal self-contained unit test -- the only thing I observe is **3x** to **10x** increase in test elapsed time for *MySQL* 5.7 compared to other *MySQL* versions, but the DDL doesn't hang forever:

[image]

All *MySQL* versions are either stock versions for *Windows* or *Debian Linux* downloaded from [www.mysql.com](https://www.mysql.com/) with minimal changes to `my.cnf`, or the official *Docker* images.

**Questions:**

1. Is it indeed technically possible for *MySQL* to delay the execution of `ALTER TABLE` DDL forever? Or what I'm observing is just a very busy database instance? Is it possible to either

   - request that `ALTER TABLE` is executed interruptibly, i. e. an error is returned by the database if a certain time-out is exceeded, or
   - force all other connections which can potentially place even a `SHARED` lock on the table or some of its rows to pause, so that they don't intervene while the DDL is being executed?
2. When dealing with the original integration test timing out, how can I further diagnose the situation from *MySQL* side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR — commit your transactions to unblock your ALTER TABLE.**

---

Yes, ALTER TABLE can block for a long time. It may seem like forever. It's actually the value of [lock_wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lock_wait_timeout), which is 31536000 seconds by default, or 365 days.

In MySQL, DDL statements like ALTER TABLE require an exclusive [metadata lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/metadata-locking.html) on the table. The purpose is to make sure you don't ALTER TABLE from two concurrent sessions at the same time.

DML statement like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE also hold "shared" metadata locks. Shared locks can be held by multiple sessions concurrently, but block exclusive locks, because exclusive locks require that they be the only one to hold any type of lock on the table.

Documentation states:

> This locking approach has the implication that a table that is being used by a transaction within one session cannot be used in DDL statements by other sessions until the transaction ends.

The purpose of DML statements holding a metadata lock is so they can preserve their repeatable-read view of the table without worry that another session is doing DROP TABLE or ALTER TABLE to compromise their view of the table. This locking is necessary because MySQL does not have versioned metadata ([they are gradually working toward that](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-data-dictionary-architecture-and-design/)).

This means a transaction that has run a simple SELECT and doesn't commit will block a DROP TABLE or ALTER TABLE that requires a locking change.

There is some nuance with the introduction of online DDL.

[Online DDL Performance and Concurrency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-index-concurrency.html) describes in more detail that an ALTER TABLE starts out by acquiring a shared metadata lock, so the uncommitted transaction will not block it. But the next phase may upgrade the shared metadata lock to an exclusive metadata lock, if the nature of the ALTER TABLE change requires it. At this point, the lock acquisition is blocked because the other transaction still holds its own metadata lock.

Online DDL doesn't apply to every type of ALTER TABLE operation; some still require exclusive locks. Changing a data type, for example, as you are doing, requires an exclusive lock. See [Online DDL Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't specifically create **long-running** transactions, but in a scenario with multiple writers which are constantly creating short transactions it takes indeed forever for the DDL to complete.

Comment: I suggestion you query `information_schema.innodb_trx join information_schema.processlist on processlist.id=innodb_trx.trx_mysql_thread` or `show engine innodb status` when you see DDL taking a long time, and figure out whether it is waiting for a lock, or if it's executing.

Comment: Hey @BillKarwin, this answer was super helpful! A followup question: In mysql 5.6+, while the DDL is waiting to acquire the exclusive lock, it shouldn't necessarily block queries or DML right? So if we see evidence of DML being held up due to the DDL, will setting lock=None do the trick to execute the DDL safely?

Selfish plug for my own question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822710/why-did-adding-an-index-to-a-table-in-mysql-5-6-cause-a-deadlock?noredirect=1#comment112859247_63822710

Comment: I commented on your question.