# MYSQL 5.6.10 ANALYZE TABLE lock issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-5.6, table-locking

I ran the analyze table command on production mysql db without knowing it would prevent me from selecting the contents of the table. This caused production site to go down :( How long can it take for the lock to release? Also, would recreating the db from a backup solve the problem / get rid of the locks?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ANALYZE TABLE waits to acquire a metadata lock. While it's waiting, any SQL query against the table waits for ANALYZE TABLE.

ANALYZE TABLE is normally pretty quick, i.e. 1-3 seconds. But that quick operation doesn't *start* until it can acquire the metadata lock.

It can't acquire the metadata lock while you have long-running transactions going against the table. So if you want this to run faster, finish your transactions.

See my answer to [MySQL failing to ALTER TABLE which is being actively written to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902557/mysql-failing-to-alter-table-which-is-being-actively-written-to/51902803#51902803) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

[ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) quite clearly says 'During the analysis, the table is locked with a read lock for InnoDB and MyISAM'.

You can `KILL {connection number}` in SQL to stop the command.

Note: you probably should update to a more recent version of MySQL-5.6.

Comment: I did that but it keeps on creating more processes.